# How can I generate a list or array of sequential integers in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, guava, apache-commons

Is there a short and sweet way to generate a `List<Integer>`, or perhaps an  `Integer[]` or `int[]`, with sequential values from some `start` value to an `end` value?

That is, something shorter than, but equivalent to<sup>1</sup> the following:

```
void List<Integer> makeSequence(int begin, int end) {
  List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>(end - begin + 1);
  for (int i=begin; i<=end; i++) {
    ret.add(i);
  }
  return ret;  
}
```

The use of guava is fine.

**Update:**

### Performance Analysis

Since this question has received several good answers, both using native Java 8 and third party libraries, I thought I'd test the performance of all the solutions.

The first test simply tests creating a list of 10 elements `[1..10]` using the following methods:

- **classicArrayList**: the code given above in my question (and essentially the same as adarshr's answer).
- **eclipseCollections**: the code given in [Donald's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36350104/149138) below using Eclipse Collections 8.0.
- **guavaRange**: the code given in [daveb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10242491/149138) below. Technically, this doesn't create a `List<Integer>` but rather a `ContiguousSet<Integer>` - but since it implements `Iterable<Integer>` in-order, it mostly works for my purposes.
- **intStreamRange**: the code given in [Vladimir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22829036/149138) below, which uses `IntStream.rangeClosed()` - which was introduced in Java 8.
- **streamIterate**: the code given in [Catalin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36114723/149138) below which also uses `IntStream` functionality introduced in Java 8.

Here are the results in kilo-operations per second (higher numbers are better), for all the above with lists of size 10:

[image: List creation throughput]

... and again for lists of size 10,000:

[image]

That last chart is correct - the solutions other than Eclipse and Guava are too slow to even get a single pixel bar! The fast solutions are 10,000 to 20,000 *times* faster than the rest.

What's going on here, of course, is that the guava and eclipse solutions don't actually materialize any kind of 10,000 element list - they are simply fixed-size wrappers around the start and endpoints. Each element is created as needed during iteration. Since we don't actually iterate in this test, the cost is deferred. All of the other solutions actually materialize the full list in memory and pay a heavy price in a creation-only benchmark.

Let's do something a bit more realistic and also iterate over all the integers, summing them. So in the case of the `IntStream.rangeClosed` variant, the benchmark looks like:

```
@Benchmark
public int intStreamRange() {
    List<Integer> ret = IntStream.rangeClosed(begin, end).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());  

    int total = 0;
    for (int i : ret) {
        total += i;
    }
    return total;  
}
```

Here, the pictures changes a lot, although the non-materializing solutions are still the fastest. Here's length=10:

[image: List<Integer> Iteration (length=10)]

... and length = 10,000:

[image: List<Integer> Iteration (length=10,000)]

The long iteration over many elements evens things up a lot, but eclipse and guava remain more than twice as fast even on the 10,000 element test.

So if you *really* want a `List<Integer>`, eclipse collections seems like the best choice - but of course if you use streams in a more native way (e.g., forgetting `.boxed()` and doing a reduction in the primitive domain) you'll probably end up faster than all these variants.

---

<sup>1</sup> Perhaps with the exception of error handling, e.g., if `end` < `begin`, or if the size exceeds some implementation or JVM limits (e.g., arrays larger than `2^31-1`.

Comment: For apache commons, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5744861/560302

Answer (score 291, accepted):

With Java 8 it is so simple so it doesn't even need separate method anymore:

```
List<Integer> range = IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end)
    .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And in Java 16 or later:

```
List<Integer> range = IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end)
    .boxed().toList();
```

Comment: I added performance results for this answer above with the label **intStreamRange**.

Comment: Requires API 24+

Comment: How would I turn those numbers into strings?

Comment: @FelixJassler `IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.toList())`, for example.

Comment: you could even do: `List<Integer> range = IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end)
            .boxed().toList();` instead of the collector

Comment: Even so, speaking only for myself, I prefer a separate function because there are enough intermediate steps in there to obscure the logic of what's going on

Answer (score 31):

Well, this one liner might qualify (uses [Guava Ranges](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained))

```
ContiguousSet<Integer> integerList = ContiguousSet.create(Range.closedOpen(0, 10), DiscreteDomain.integers());
System.out.println(integerList);
```

This doesn't create a `List<Integer>`, but `ContiguousSet` offers much the same functionality, in particular implementing `Iterable<Integer>` which allows `foreach` implementation in the same way as `List<Integer>`.

In older versions (somewhere before Guava 14) you could use this:

```
ImmutableList<Integer> integerList = Ranges.closedOpen(0, 10).asSet(DiscreteDomains.integers()).asList();
System.out.println(integerList);
```

Both produce:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `asList()` there unless you really needed a `List`... the `ContiguousSet` produced by `asSet` is lightweight (it just needs the range and the domain), but `asList()` will create a list that actually stores all the elements in memory (currently).

Comment: Agreed.  The OP was asking for a List or array though, otherwise I would have left it out

Comment: I believe for 18.0, `Range` exists but not `Ranges` and they have done away with the `asSet` method.  In my older version, `asSet` is deprecated and it appears that they have removed it.  Ranges apparently are only to be used for contiguous collections and they have enforced it though I do love this solution.

Comment: The API now requires code similar to this:
ContiguousSet.create(Range.closed(1, count), DiscreteDomain.integers()

Comment: I added performance results for this answer above with the label **guavaRange**.

Answer (score 21):

The following one-liner Java 8 version will generate [ 1, 2 ,3 ... 10 ]. The first arg of `iterate` is the first nr in the sequence, and the first arg of `limit` is the last number.

```
List<Integer> numbers = Stream.iterate(1, n -> n + 1)
                              .limit(10)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I added performance results for this answer above with the label **streamIterate**.

Comment: As a point of clarification, the limit arg isn't the last number, it's the number of Integers in the list.

Comment: When compared to the other approaches, this one allows you to create a sequence of integers with a step (e.g `n -> n + 5`), which is what brought me to this post in the first place.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [`Interval`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/list/Interval.html) class from [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

```
List<Integer> range = Interval.oneTo(10);
range.forEach(System.out::print);  // prints 12345678910
```

The `Interval` class is lazy, so doesn't store all of the values.

```
LazyIterable<Integer> range = Interval.oneTo(10);
System.out.println(range.makeString(",")); // prints 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Your method would be able to be implemented as follows:

```
public List<Integer> makeSequence(int begin, int end) {
    return Interval.fromTo(begin, end);
}
```

If you would like to avoid boxing ints as Integers, but would still like a list structure as a result, then you can use [`IntList`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/primitive/IntList.html) with [`IntInterval`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/list/primitive/IntInterval.html) from Eclipse Collections.

```
public IntList makeSequence(int begin, int end) {
    return IntInterval.fromTo(begin, end);
}
```

`IntList` has the methods `sum()`, `min()`, `minIfEmpty()`, `max()`, `maxIfEmpty()`, `average()` and `median()` available on the interface.

**Update for clarity: 11/27/2017**

An `Interval` is a `List<Integer>`, but it is lazy and immutable.  It is extremely useful for generating test data, especially if you deal a lot with collections.  If you want you can easily copy an interval to a `List`, `Set` or `Bag` as follows:

```
Interval integers = Interval.oneTo(10);
Set<Integer> set = integers.toSet();
List<Integer> list = integers.toList();
Bag<Integer> bag = integers.toBag();
```

An `IntInterval` is an `ImmutableIntList` which extends `IntList`.  It also has converter methods.

```
IntInterval ints = IntInterval.oneTo(10);
IntSet set = ints.toSet();
IntList list = ints.toList();
IntBag bag = ints.toBag();
```

An `Interval` and an `IntInterval` do not have the same `equals` contract.

**Update for [Eclipse Collections 9.0](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/releases/tag/9.0.0)**

You can now create primitive collections from primitive streams.  There are `withAll` and `ofAll` methods depending on your preference.  If you are curious, I explain why we have both [here](https://medium.com/@donraab/preposition-preference-1f1c709b098b).  These methods exist for mutable and immutable Int/Long/Double Lists, Sets, Bags and Stacks.

```
Assert.assertEquals(
        IntInterval.oneTo(10),
        IntLists.mutable.withAll(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)));

Assert.assertEquals(
        IntInterval.oneTo(10),
        IntLists.immutable.withAll(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)));
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Comment: I added performance results for this answer above with the label **eclipseCollections**.

Comment: Neat.  I updated my answer with an additional primitive version that should avoid any boxing.

Answer (score 7):

This is the shortest I could get using Core Java.

```
List<Integer> makeSequence(int begin, int end) {
  List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList(end - begin + 1);

  for(int i = begin; i <= end; i++, ret.add(i));

  return ret;  
}
```

Comment: You can shave off a couple more characters by changing that loop to `for(int i = begin; i <= end; ret.add(i++));` :)

Comment: I'm not really sure that moving the `ret.add(i)` part into the for loop increment makes this "shorter".  I guess by that logic if I wrote it all on one line it would be shorter :)

Comment: @BeeOnRope Yes, definitely not the shortest, but shorter by two lines for sure :) As I said, this is the closest we can come to shortening it in Core Java.

Comment: I added performance results for this answer above with the label **classicArrayList**.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Guava Ranges](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained)

You can get a `SortedSet` by using

```
ImmutableSortedSet<Integer> set = Ranges.open(1, 5).asSet(DiscreteDomains.integers());
// set contains [2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int[] arr = IntStream.rangeClosed(2, 5).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// [2, 3, 4, 5]

Integer[] boxedArr = IntStream.rangeClosed(2, 5)
  .boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(boxedArr));

// Since Java 16
List<Integer> list1 = IntStream.rangeClosed(2, 5)
  .boxed().toList();
System.out.println(list1);

List<Integer> list2 = IntStream.rangeClosed(2, 5)
  .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list2);

List<Integer> list3 = Arrays.asList(boxedArr);
System.out.println(list3);

List<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.rangeClosed(2, 5).forEachOrdered(list4::add);
System.out.println(list4);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest I could find.

List version

```
public List<Integer> makeSequence(int begin, int end)
{
    List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<Integer>(++end - begin);

    for (; begin < end; )
        ret.add(begin++);

    return ret;
}
```

Array Version

```
public int[] makeSequence(int begin, int end)
{
    if(end < begin)
        return null;

    int[] ret = new int[++end - begin];
    for (int i=0; begin < end; )
        ret[i++] = begin++;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: `for (; begin < end; )` is better written `while (begin < end)`

Answer (score -2):

This one might works for you....

```
void List<Integer> makeSequence(int begin, int end) {

  AtomicInteger ai=new AtomicInteger(begin);
  List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList(end-begin+1);

  while ( end-->begin) {

    ret.add(ai.getAndIncrement());

  }
  return ret;  
}
```

Comment: Using AtomicInteger is very heavy for ressources, around ten time slower in my test. But it is secure for multithread. *end<begin* not verified

Comment: The use of AtomicInteger doesn't make sense inside of a method. All the sentences in a method call are run sequentially by the thread that called the method, so you get nothing from the AtomicInteger but slowdown and annoying getAndIncrement() calls.