# Array exercise with loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have to store even numbers using array until 20, but when I run, just show me the number 0
I would appreciate some help.

```
int num[] = new int[20];

for(int i = 0; i <=10; i++){
    System.out.println(i);

    if(i%2 == 0){
        System.out.println("even number " +num[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `num[i]`? Why do you use it?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: It's obvious it is an even number. He just didn't initialize his int array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java when you define an array of int all the elements are initialized to 0.

All the elements in num[] are 0. Because you didn't assign any value to them.

Try this.

```
int num[] = new int[20];

for(int i = 0; i <=10; i++){
    num[i] = i;
    System.out.println(i);

    if(i%2 == 0){

    System.out.println("even number " +num[i]);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you assumed you were going to be given an array that was automatically populated with the numbers 1 to 20 or 0 to 20. You have to add these numbers to the array yourself. By default, the array will contain the number 0 for every index from 0 to 19 (20 elements). You can use this method to autopopulate the array:

```
void List<Integer> makeSequence(int begin, int end) 
{
   List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList(end-begin+1);

   for(int i = begin; i <= end; i++, ret.add(i));

   return ret;  
}

...

List<Integer> seq = makeSequence(0, 19);
int num[] = new int[seq.size()];
seq.toArray(num); // fill the array
```

Of course, once you have a `List<Integer>` you could have just used a `List` in the first place.

makeSequence courtesy of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10242489/2591612).

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign that number to your array like:

```
int index = -1;
if(i%2 == 0){
    num[++index] = i;
    System.out.println("even number " +num[index]);
}
```

Comment: this way he would have 0 at odd index

Comment: Yea you're right, but i want to deliver the idea, and he is printing the current index, so he will not notice the odd indexs, anyway  i updated the answer.