# List.fill(int)(method()) equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, list, scala, function

In Scala, there is a method that looks something like this.

```
List[(A, B)] = List.fill(n)(doSomething(arg))
```

My question is if there is any way to do this in Java, or if it would have to be done through a series of lengthy `for`s and what have you.

Java does have `Collections.fill` but it doesn't seem to do what I want it to do.

Scala implementation is as follows:

```
def buyCoffee(cc: CreditCard): (Coffee, Charge) =
{
    val cup = new Coffee()
    (cup, Charge(cc, cup.price))
}
def buyCoffees(cc: CreditCard, n: Int): (List[Coffee], Charge) =
{
    val p: List[(Coffee, Charge)] = List.fill(n)(buyCoffee(cc))
}
```

This does not seem achievable in Java to me, or not from what I know of Java or what I have been able to find in the documentation thus far.

This Scala code can be found on Page 7 of *Functional Programming in Scala*
by Paul Chiusana and Rúnar Bjarnason.

Comment: what is the implementation of the `doSomehing()` ?

Comment: `Collections.fill` will replace all items inside a collections with the specified object. You need to do something special, like only fill if a conditions is met?

Comment: I've updated with the Scala implementation of the relevant section.

Comment: @kunpapa Yeah, as long as it's from Java 7 or before. Java 8 is not applicable here, unfortunately. We could use something like the example below if Java 8 were usable. I'd like to see what anyone could come up with or suggestions on what to use for Java7 implementation of this.

Answer (score 6):

There is an equivalent with Java 8 :

- Use a Stream to generate a sequence
- For each value of the sequence, map it using whichever method you want
- Collect the result

Example :

```
List<Result> collect = IntStream.range(0, 5)
                      .mapToObj(i -> doSomething(i))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());

public Result doSomething(Integer i) {
  return ...;
}
```

Comment: Oohh yes, forgot Java 8. I'm beginning to see this anywhere. Seems too powerfull.

Comment: I'm trying to do this with Java 7 or less, if at all possible.

Comment: @kunpapa Java 8 with its Streams and lambdas enable scala-like functional programming.

Comment: @m482 Functionnal programming can be obtained in Java 7 using Guava. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242380/short-and-sweet-sequence-of-integers-in-java

Answer (score 1):

There is a [JEP for creating small collections](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269) or [the issue is easier to read](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8048330).

It shows a couple of idioms, one of which uses an initializer. A Java 8 version of `fill`:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class j {
  public static <T> List<T> fill(int n, Function<Integer, T> f) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<T>(n) {{
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) add(f.apply(i));
    }});
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> values = fill(10, i -> 2 * i);
    for (int x : values) System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

I haven't looked for a JEP for other conveniences, but it's clear that these API are on their minds.

Comment: Dude, that's actually `tabulate`. `fill` would take a `Supplier`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple for format:

```
ArrayList<Coffee> array = new ArrayList<Coffee>();
// array.add("Coffe Expresso") ...
CreditCard cc = new CreditCard("1234 4321 1234 4321");
for(Coffee obj : array){
   obj = new Coffee("Coffee - no sugar");
   buyCoffee(obj, cc);
}

public void buyCoffee(Coffee coffee, CreditCard cc){
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what it is you are trying to "achieve" in java, that seems "unachievable" to you.

```
List list = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) list.add(buyCoffee(cc));
```

is hardly much "lengthier" than what you had in scala. What is the problem you see with it?

Java is not a functional language, and there is no point in trying to use it as if it was: if you want functional, just use scala.

Even the solutions people suggested for java8, do not look pretty (longer, than this one), are harder to read, and have subtle problems (such as, `byCoffee` cannot throw exceptions, a lot of intermediate collections are allocated etc.)

If you are writing java code, it is better to use idiomatic java, unless there is a rational justification against it.

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(n)`

Answer (score 0):

This is surely the roundabout way of answering the question, and is certainly not a replacement for "fill" or other functional-programming methods. However, it works for this implementation in Java, which is the main issue at this point.

```
class Cafe
{

Results buyCoffee(CreditCard cc)
{
    Coffee cup = new Coffee();
    List<Results> myList = new ArrayList<Results>();

    myList.add(0, new Results(cup, new Charge(cc, cup.price)));
    return myList.get(0);
}


Map<List<Coffee>, Charge> buyCoffees(CreditCard cc, int n)
{
    List<Results> purchases = new ArrayList<Results>(n);
    for(int a = 0; a < n; a++)
    {
        Results r = new Results();
        r = buyCoffee(cc);
        purchases.add(r);
    }

    List<Coffee> coffeeList = new ArrayList<Coffee>(n);
    List<Charge> chargeList = new ArrayList<Charge>(n);

    for(int b = 0; b < n; b++)
    {
        Coffee c = purchases.get(b).ThisCoffee;
        Charge charge = purchases.get(b).ThisCharge;
        coffeeList.add(c);
        chargeList.add(charge);
    }

    Charge fc = new Charge();
    Double[] ChargeAmountArray = new Double[n];

    for(int d = 0; d < n; d++)
    {
        Double x = chargeList.get(d).amount;
        ChargeAmountArray[d] = x;
    }

    double sum = 0;

    for(Double d: ChargeAmountArray)
    {
        sum += d;           // 50.0@n=5, 100.0@n=10
    }

    Charge finalCharge = new Charge(cc, sum);

    Map<List<Coffee>, Charge> map;
    map = new HashMap<List<Coffee>, Charge>();
    map.put(coffeeList, finalCharge);
    return map;
}
}
```