# How to create a int[] or a Collection<Integer> with the value 0,1,2,...,N in one line in Java using lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda

I would like to do something like this:

```
int[] seq = new int[N];
for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {
    seq[i] = i;
}
```

...in one line, and i am wondering if it is possible with lambda expression.

If it works with `ArrayList<Integer>`, it is okay for me.

Comment: I'm just wondering how useful is this, no offense. Every `seq[k]`, can be replaced with `k` in other parts of code and you need no additional memory...

Comment: I want to use 'Collections.shuffle' after

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? It was asked here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058366/shuffle-a-list-of-integers-with-java-8-streams-api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate a list or array of sequential integers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242380/how-can-i-generate-a-list-or-array-of-sequential-integers-in-java)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `IntStream.range()`:

```
int[] seq = IntStream.range(0, N).toArray();
```

or `IntStream.rangeClosed()` if you want to include `N`:

```
int[] seq = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, N).toArray();
```

Answer (score 14):

Starting from **Java 9** you can use the three-argument [`IntStream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntPredicate-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-):

```
int[] seq = IntStream.iterate(0, x -> x < N, x -> x + 1).toArray();
```

Where:

`IntStream.iterate​(int seed, IntPredicate hasNext, IntUnaryOperator next):`

- `seed` - the initial element;
- `hasNext` - a predicate to apply to elements to determine when the stream must terminate;
- `next` - a function to be applied to the previous element to produce a new element.

Answer (score 2):

A [**BitSet**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) would do too. Though then without lambda.

```
BitSet bset = new BitSet(N); // Initial capacity for N bits.
bset.set(0, N); // Set a range to true for 0 upto N-1.
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion - but this is neither one line, nor produces an `int[]` or `Collection<Integer>` as requested by the OP.

Comment: @Hulk and it does not use a lambda stylish syntax. However (1) BitSet is equivalent to a `Set<Integer>`, (2) BitSet can set ranges, (3) the use case seems to indicate that BitSet might be appropriate, (4) BitSet might be more efficient, (5) the code is actually more compact as a foreach.

Comment: Agreed - and it can be converted into an `IntStream` over the indices of the set bits via `bset.stream()`, if needed. I'd still prefer `IntStream.range(0,N)` without further information, but +1 for creativity

Comment: `BitSet` is a highly underestimated class in Java, +1 for helping make this class more known to the world.

Comment: @JoopEggen Re (3) the use case seems to be applying `Collections.shuffle()` as per OPs comment. Seems a `BitSet` doesn't make much sense then.

Comment: @BlackJack you are right, I overlooked that. Maybe a permutation for something like blackjack. I leave the answer for other similar questions as there is an already accepted answer.