# Get missing number from array with an efficient algorithm?‽?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance, int

I am doing the following programming exercise: [Number Zoo Patrol](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5276c18121e20900c0000235). The statement is:

> Background:
>
> You're working in a number zoo, and it seems that one of the numbers
>   has gone missing!
>
> Zoo workers have no idea what number is missing, and are too
>   incompetent to figure it out, so they're hiring you to do it for them.
>
> In case the zoo loses another number, they want your program to work
>   regardless of how many numbers there are in total. Task:
>
> Write a function that takes a shuffled array of unique numbers from 1
>   to n with one element missing (which can be any number including n).
>   Return this missing number. Examples:
>
> findNumber([1, 3, 4]) should be 2 findNumber([1, 2, 3]) should be 4
>   findNumber([4, 2, 3]) should be 1

I have difficulties because of it is the first exercise where the time complexity is being tested. There is a test which checks that your algorithm executes in less than one second for huge arrays. The following is the test I am writting about:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.Timeout;

public class NumberZooPatrolSampleTest {

    @Rule
    public Timeout globalTimeout = new Timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    @Test
    public void testDescriptionExamples() {
        assertEquals(2, findMissingNumber(1, 3));
        assertEquals(1, findMissingNumber(2, 3, 4));
        assertEquals(12, findMissingNumber(13, 11, 10, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 7, 8));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPerformanceIsLinear() {
        // Solutions with linear runtime should finish in about 200 to 300 ms.
        // 1. Generate an array with 999,999 numbers with increasing and
        //    decreasing values interleaved so sorting algorithms which
        //    are able detect pre-sorted arrays would still need
        //    at least loglinear time.
        // 2. Find the missing number 100 times.
        int[] numbers = generateNumbers(1_000_000, 66_667);
        for (int i = 0; i < 249_999; i++) {
            int temp = numbers[i * 2];
            numbers[i * 2] = numbers[999_997 - i * 2];
            numbers[999_997 - i * 2] = temp;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            findMissingNumber(numbers.clone());
    }

    private static int findMissingNumber(int ... numbers) {
        return NumberZooPatrol.findMissingNumber(numbers);
    }

    private static int[] generateNumbers(int bound, int missingNumber) {
        if (missingNumber < 1 || missingNumber > bound)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing number is not in allowed range");
        int[] numbers = new int[bound - 1];
        int pos = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= bound; i++)
            if (i != missingNumber)
                numbers[pos++] = i;
        return numbers;
    }

}
```

My first aproach was to compare number by number in the array with the one there should be in that position:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class NumberZooPatrol {
  public static int findMissingNumber(int[] numbers) {
    int[] clone = numbers.clone();
    Arrays.sort(clone);
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < clone.length; i++){
      if(clone[i] != i+1){
        break;
      }
    }
    return i+1;
  }
}
```

However it does not pass the time complexity test.

Besides I used another approach where we get the difference between the sum of the range and the current array sum:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class NumberZooPatrol {
  public static int findMissingNumber(int[] numbers) {
    if(numbers.length == 0) return 1;
    int[] clone = numbers.clone();
    Arrays.sort(clone);
    int range = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,clone[clone.length-1]).sum();
    int sum = IntStream.of(clone).sum();
    return range - sum == 0 ? clone.length + 1 : range - sum;
  }
}
```

And it also times out when we execute the time complexity test.

In addition I have read:

- [How can I generate a list or array of sequential integers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242380/how-can-i-generate-a-list-or-array-of-sequential-integers-in-java)
- [How to sum a list of integers with java streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125296/how-to-sum-a-list-of-integers-with-java-streams)
- [Make copy of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-an-array)

How could we get the missing number from array with an efficient algorithm?‽?

Comment: Remove the sorting from your second attempt.

Comment: A fact you should bear in mind: sorting an arbitrary array always takes more than linear time. So never involve a sort in an algorithm that needs to be linear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113795/quickest-way-to-find-missing-number-in-an-array-of-numbers

Comment: Solution here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-missing-number/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in O(n) time complexity using two approaches:

1. You can find the sum of numbers using n(n+1)/2 formula and subtract the actual sum to get the missing number.
2. You can also XOR all the numbers in the range 1 to n and also the numbers in the input. The result will be the missing number. This works because, XOR of a number with itself is zero and 0 XOR any number is the number itself.

eg:
If input is [1, 3, 4] and missing number is 2.

```
(1 XOR 2 XOR 3 XOR 4) XOR (1 XOR 3 XOR 4) = 
(1 XOR 1) XOR (3 XOR 3) XOR (4 XOR 4) XOR 2 =
0 XOR 0 XOR 0 XOR 2 = 
0 XOR 2 =
2
```