# Removing a number from array in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, integer

I would like to remove a particular number from the array

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = i;
        }
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

This is creating numbers from 0-7
But I dont need 0,I need value from 1-7

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242380/how-can-i-generate-a-list-or-array-of-sequential-integers-in-java) has couple of suggestions.

Comment: Why don't u start your for-loop with `int i = 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first value written into your array is 0 because you initialize `i` with 0 in the for loop.

Therefore your loop will only insert the values 0 - **6**.

Change this initialisation to `i = 1` and in addition you also need to change the condition of the for loop to `arr.length + 1` or `i <= arr.length`, so it will count up to 7.

```java
Integer[] arr = new Integer[7];
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length + 1; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
}
```

What you also can do instead of changing the loop itself, is to change the loop body. Just add 1 to i when assigning it to arr[i]:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = i + 1;
}
```

In this case i will count from 0 to 6, and assign 1 to 7 to your array

Comment: But when I am changing i to 1 I am getting array with 1-6 and one elemnt is null value

Comment: sry. i missed that point at first sight. Adapted my answer to meet your criteria. Of course you also need to change the condtion to `i < arr.length + 1` or `i <= arr.length` in this case

Comment: I also added a imho easier solution at the bottom of my answer. You also can just change the assignment-statement in the loop body.

Comment: Yes thats is working

Answer (score 0):

Change your `int i = 0` to `int i = 1` like this:

```
   Integer[] arr = new Integer[7];
        for(int i = 1; i <8; i++){
            int value = i-1;
            arr[value] = i;
        }

        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                System.out.println("Result:"+arr[i]);
        }
```

Console message:

```
Result:7
Result:2
Result:6
Result:5
Result:4
Result:1
Result:3
```

Comment: But when I am changing i to 1 I am getting array with 1-6 and one elemnt is null value

Comment: Here you go. Now you have your 1-6 with a shuffle. Cheers!

Comment: I am not diplaying the contents..I need the array without value 0. From this array I am doing something else